# Android boot complete event not received

Tags: android

I tried to configure my application to receive even on Application startup.
This code doesn`t work (even the log messages are not logged)

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".BackgroundService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>
</application>
<receiver android:name=".StartupReceiver" >
    <!-- This intent filter receives the boot completed event -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And my receiver

```
public class StartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public StartupReceiver() {
        Log.e("Tag", "STARTUP construct");
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // start your service here
        Log.e("Tag", "STARTUP");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class));
    }
}
```

Can you see any mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake in your manifest. The receiver should be declared inside the `<application>` tag.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".BackgroundService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>


    <receiver android:name=".StartupReceiver" >
        <!-- This intent filter receives the boot completed event -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full namespace for your receiver name:

```
<receiver android:name="com.whatever.StartupReceiver">
```